# scroll ul li via button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

see link :http://liveweave.com/TE5gGp

i want to scroll when scroll up button is click how to make it work

when u goto bottom and click scrollup it directly goes to start , but it should go slowly like when clicked first time it scroll up to 1 content ,and so on

```
(function () {



    $('#scrollup').click(function() {
        $(".sidebar-menu").animate({
        scrollTop:  scrolled
        });
    });

})();
```

Comment: http://liveweave.com/fdfzJw you shold declare scrolled variable thats missing

Comment: not working when u goto bottom and click scrollup it directly goes to start , but it should go slowly like when clicked first time it scroll up to 1 content ,and so on

better let me update question

Comment: ok I dint read your qn completely first time just saw the error and posted with correction, I got it now. are you still looking for answer?

Comment: is it possible to scroll one li element at time ?

Comment: yes its possible you should subtract li item height from scrollTop

Comment: how to do it can u update link??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var scrolled = 10;
 $('#scrollup').click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-menu").animate({
    scrollTop:  $(".sidebar-menu").scrollTop() - scrolled
    });
```

It ll slide you up bit by bit. Replace 10 by the value you want. If you want to scrolltop to 0, use `scrollTop:0`